# Chrome: Getting iFrame and inserting into body

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've got the following code which works fine in Firefox...

```
if (!iFrame) iFrame = outerDoc.getElementById('_dialog_iframe');
var iFrameDoc = iFrame.contentWindow.document; // get iframe doc
```

and the Chrome version...

```
if (!iFrame) iFrame = outerDoc.getElementById('_dialog_iframe');
var iFrameDoc = iFrame.document; // get iframe doc
```

I'm testing the code be getting `iFrameDoc.body` when I run the FireFox code in Firefox it works fine. However, the Chrome code returns `undefined`. Why? How do I fix this so that it'll work fine in Chrome?

Answer (score 11):

If the iframe element has a `document` property in Chrome then I'm surprised, and it's non-standard and not supported in other browsers. The standards-based property is `contentDocument`, and to support other browsers you can use `contentWindow.document`. The following will work in all major browsers:

```
var iFrameDoc = iFrame.contentDocument || iFrame.contentWindow.document;
```

Comment: I had a similar issue, and your code works. What is weird is that removing the params "sandbox='allow-same-origin allow-scripts'" in the iframe it works fine anyway.