# iframe.contentWindow.document Chrome alternative?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome

How would I call the following in Chrome? `iframe.contentWindow.document`

Comment: What do you mean? That's not a function so you wouldn't call it.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp

Comment: I answered this earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002334/chrome-getting-iframe-and-inserting-into-body/5002576#5002576

Answer (score 8):

Chrome does in fact support `iframe.contentWindow.document`, but there's a little wrinkle that you've probably fallen prey to: if the file set to the `iframe.src` property is being accessed locally (i.e. using the "file://" protocol), that property is inaccessible in Chrome. This will happen if you specify a relative file address and attempt to test the script without using a web-server like IIS or Apache (by simply double-clicking it). The same also applies to `iframe.contentDocument`.

I ran into a similar problem where, for some odd reason, Chrome would not accept event handlers dynamically attached to iframes. Then I found the note in [this article](http://help.dottoro.com/ljctglqj.php), tested with Apache, and hey presto, it suddenly began to work.

Answer (score 6):

`iframe.contentDocument` is what you want.

See also [Chrome: Getting iFrame and inserting into body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002334/chrome-getting-iframe-and-inserting-into-body/5002576#5002576)

Comment: why when using this does.. `.defaultView.getComputedStyle` of the `iframe.contentDocument` say ...`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getComputedStyle' of undefined` ?

Comment: @Skizit: It works fine for me. Do you have a test page or example code to show the problem?

Comment: @Šime: It does seem to work in the current version of Chrome. I'm not sure it always has though; I think I'd read somewhere that it didn't. `contentDocument` is preferable where it exists anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
<iframe id="popupFrame" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var popupFrame = document.getElementById('popupFrame');
var iFrameDoc;
if (switchAccountsPopupFrame.document) {
    iFrameDoc = switchAccountsPopupFrame.document; // works with IE9 and FF9
}
else {
    // Google Chrome (16.0.912.75 m)
    iFrameDoc = switchAccountsPopupFrame.ownerDocument;
}
....
</script>
```

Comment: *ownerDocument* is what it sounds like it is. It's the document of the owner of the iFrame, i. e. *document*.